# How to pass uploaded pdf file to the variable. (PDF.JS)

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, pdftotext

Reference : http://git.macropus.org/2011/11/pdftotext/example/

In this project developer has taken a pdf as input and pass it to variable "input". **I want to create an upload menu/dropzone** so that anyone can  upload their pdf and it automatically get passed to the variable "input" and text can be extracted. **I am able to upload the file** **but don't know how to pass that pdf to the variable "input".**

```
<body>
    <form id="upload" method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div id="drop">
            Drop Here
                <a>Browse</a>
            <input id="inputx" src="./"type="file" name="upl" multiple />
          </div>

          <ul>
            <!-- The file uploads will be shown here -->
          </ul>

        </form>
```

Now using this form a pdf will be uploaded now we have to pass it the variable "input ".

```
          <script>     
          var input = document.getElementById("input");
          var processor = document.getElementById("processor");
          var output = document.getElementById("output");

          window.addEventListener("message", function(event){
            if (event.source != processor.contentWindow) return;

            switch (event.data){
              case "ready":
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
                xhr.open('GET', input.getAttribute("src"), true);
                xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";

                xhr.onload = function(event) {
                  processor.contentWindow.postMessage(this.response, "*");
                };

                xhr.send();

              break;

              default:
                 output.innerHTML = event.data.replace(/\s+/g, " ");
                break;
            }
          }, true);
          </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to point Pdf.js to the copy of the file you've uploaded.

In your code above, Pdf.js gets its data via an XMLHttpRequest wherein it looks for a .pdf with the file name defined as the `src` attribute of the element with ID `input`:

```
xhr.open('GET', input.getAttribute("src"), true);
```

If you set  the `src` attribute on this element to the file path of the pdf you've uploaded to the server, then the script should work as-is.

Here's some code that might help you - `index.html` is a simple file upload form that calls PHP to upload a file into the same directory it (`index.html`) is served from. `file_upload.php` saves the uploaded file and sets the value of the `src` attribute on the iframe with this line:

```
<iframe id="input" src= <?php print $_FILES['userfile']['name'] ?> ></iframe>
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Converting PDF To Text using pdf.js</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <!-- the PDF file must be on the same domain as this page -->
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="file_upload.php" method="POST">
      <input id="fileInput" type="file" name="userfile"></input>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**file_upload.php**

```
<?php

$uploadfile = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}

echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";

?>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Converting PDF To Text using pdf.js</title>
  <style>
  html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow-y: hidden; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
  body { font: 13px Helvetica,sans-serif; }
  body > div { width: 48%; height: 100%; overflow-y: auto; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; }
  iframe { border: none; width: 100%; height: 100%; }
  #output { padding: 10px; box-shadow: 0 0 5px #777; border-radius: 5px; margin: 10px; }
  #processor { height: 70px; }
  </style>
</head>

  <div>
    <!-- embed the pdftotext web app as an iframe -->
    <iframe id="processor" src="../"></iframe>

    <!-- a container for the output -->
    <div id="output"><div id="intro">Extracting text from a PDF file using only Javascript.<br>Tested in Chrome 16 and Firefox 9.</div></div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <iframe id="input" src= <?php print $_FILES['userfile']['name'] ?> ></iframe>
  </div>

  <script>
  var input = document.getElementById("input");
  var processor = document.getElementById("processor");
  var output = document.getElementById("output");

  window.addEventListener("message", function(event){
    if (event.source != processor.contentWindow) return;

    switch (event.data){
      case "ready":
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
        xhr.open('GET', input.getAttribute("src"), true);
        xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";

        xhr.onload = function(event) {
          processor.contentWindow.postMessage(this.response, "*");
        };

        xhr.send();
      break;

      default:
        output.textContent = event.data.replace(/\s+/g, " ");
      break;
    }
  }, true);
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```